# How can I put the footnote only one side

Tags: footnotes

[image]

There are 7 footnote  using   Google Text to speech\footnote{http://dsasdsad}

and my document is 2 column.

I'd like to place a footnote on one side. Especially to the right-side

I saw a lot of questions, but I could only find broadening the footnote like one column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean in this way?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ftnright}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{foo}
\lipsum[2]\footnote{bah}
\lipsum[3]\footnote{baz}
\lipsum[4]\footnote{foo2}
\lipsum[5]\footnote{bah2}
\lipsum[6]\footnote{baz2}
\end{document}
```

If you want a footnote rule using this package , redefine also `\footnoterule` as you want in the preamble, for instance:

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\hrulefill\hfill\bigskip}
```